# fullCalendar, Cannot load events from event source with Django

Tags: javascript, django, fullcalendar

I am trying to load events from an event source for a fullCalendar and that doesn't seem to work. Events are not shown on the calendar, at all.

This is my js code:

```
var event={
    title: 'AAA Birthday Party',
    start: moment().startOf('month').add(23, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
};
// This is shown on the calendar
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);

// This does not show
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', '/user/watch/calendar/events/0/');
```

This is my `views.py` (it returns 200 OK)

```
def watch_events(request, uid):
    test = {
        "events": [
            {
                "title": "Lesson1",
                "id": "821",
                "start": "2016-01-01 09:00:00",
                "end": "2016-01-01 10:30:00"
            },
            {
                "title": "Lesson2",
                "id": "822",
                "start": "2016-01-01 10:00:00",
                "end": "2016-01-01 11:30:00"
            }
        ],
        "color": 'yellow',
        "textColor": 'black'
    }
    return JsonResponse(test)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question.

Comment: Is the url you've shown there the same that would be constructed with the `url` template tag? (I'm wondering if it needs to use the full path)

Comment: Yes. However, the url is not the problem. It returns 200 and the json object. There is something that `addEventSource` doesn't like about my JSON object. Unfortunately, js console doesn't give me any errors. If I retrieve the JSON object through `$.ajax` (same url) and loop through the events one by one and perform a `renderEvent`, events will be displayed. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Have you tried with different date formats? The only thing different in snippets really is your first uses YMD where your second includes time

Comment: Yes. I have tried simple dates like "2016-01-01", too. I also tried this format: "2016-01-01T11:30:00", but I still get no events shown.